# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am trying to configure JSF+Spring+hibernate and I'm tying to run a test but when I use this "tx:annotation-driven" on my application-context.xml file, I get this error:

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'

Here is my application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.6.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.6.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.6.xsd
" xmlns:tool="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.56.101:1521:Gpsi"/>
        <property name="username" value="omar"/>
        <property name="password" value="omar"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
       <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>om.mycompany.model.Course</value>
                <value>om.mycompany.model.Student</value>
                <value>om.mycompany.model.Teacher</value>
            </list>
       </property>
       <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            </props>
       </property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction.manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base.package="com.mmycompany"/>
</beans>
```

and here is my CourseServiceImplTest. I have still not implemented the tests:

```
public class CourseServiceImplTest {

    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;
    private static CourseService courseService;
    public CourseServiceImplTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        courseService=(CourseService) context.getBean("courseService");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        context.close();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of getAllCourses method, of class CourseServiceImpl.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetAllCourses() {
        System.out.println("getAllCourses");
        CourseServiceImpl instance = new CourseServiceImpl();
        List expResult = null;
        List result = instance.getAllCourses();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of getCourse method, of class CourseServiceImpl.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetCourse() {
        System.out.println("getCourse");
        Integer id = null;
        CourseServiceImpl instance = new CourseServiceImpl();
        Course expResult = null;
        Course result = instance.getCourse(id);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
```

and here is the CourseServiceImpl:

```
@Service("courseService")
@Transactional
public class CourseServiceImpl implements CourseService{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Override
    public List<Course> getAllCourses() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Course").list();    
    }

    @Override
    public Course getCourse(Integer id) {
        return (Course) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Course.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Course course) {
       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(course);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have some errors in your appcontext.xml:

- Use *-2.5.xsd

  ```
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
  ```
- Typos in `tx:annotation-driven` and `context:component-scan` (. instead of -)

  ```
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mmycompany" />
  ```

Answer (score 14):

This is for others (like me :) ). Don't forget to add the spring tx jar/maven dependency.
Also correct configuration in appctx is:

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"`

, by mistake wrong configuration which others may have

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"
```

i.e., extra "/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"`

in other words what is there in xmlns(namespace) should have proper mapping in 
schemaLocation (namespace vs schema).

namespace here is : http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx

schema Doc Of namespace is : http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd

this schema of namespace later is mapped in jar to locate the path of actual xsd located in org.springframework.transaction.config

Comment: adding some spring dependencies fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: The way this answer is written is making it very difficult to understand

Answer (score 10):

For me the thing that worked was the order in which the namespaces were defined in the xsi:schemaLocation tag : [ since the version was all good and also it was transaction-manager already ]

The error was with :

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
```

AND RESOLVED WITH :

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
```

Comment: Always make sure you pair them in the order. For example, add http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx and 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd" one after the other

Answer (score 2):

I'm learning from udemy. I followed every step that my instructor show me to do.
In spring mvc crud section while setting up the devlopment environment i had the same error for:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/> and <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />
```

then i just replaced

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
```

with

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
```

and

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
```

with

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
```

actually i visited these two sites
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/ and http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/
and just added the latest version of spring-mvc and spring-tx i.e, spring-mvc-4.2.xsd  and  spring-tx-4.2.xsd

So, i suggest to try this.
Hope this helps. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One extra forward slash (/) in front of tx and the *.xml file troubled me for 8 hours!!

My mistake:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
```

Correction:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
```

Indeed one character less/more manages to keep programmers busy for hours!

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was actually a symptom of the server, hosted on AWS, lacking an IP for the external network. It would attempt to download namespaces from springframework.org and fail to make a connection.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I had this same issue. Turned out my xsi:schemaLocation entries were incorrect, so I went to the official docs and pasted theirs into mine:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html section 16.5.6

I had to add a couple more but that was ok. Next up is to find out *why* this fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Spring version and xsd version both are same.In my case I am using Spring 4.1.1 so my all xsd should be version *-4.1.xsd

Answer (score 0):

```
Any one can help for me!!!!!!!!!
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
        <context:annotation-config />(ERROR OCCUR)
        <context:component-scan base-package="hiberrSpring" /> (ERROR OCCUR)
        <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"></property>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="messageSource"
            class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>
            <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
            p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"></bean>
        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClassName="${com.mysql.jdbc.Driver}"
            p:url="${jdbc:mysql://localhost/}" p:username="${root}"
            p:password="${rajini}"></bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="configurationClass">
                <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="employeeDAO" class="hiberrSpring.EmployeeDaoImpl"></bean>
        <bean id="employeeManager" class="hiberrSpring.EmployeeManagerImpl"></bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven /> (ERROR OCCUR)
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```