# no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

in spring whenever i write `<context:annotation-config/>` in my spring.xml i get this error:-

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 81 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 81; columnNumber: 30; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.

And the content of my spring.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>

<bean id="circle" class="com.mysite.Circle">
</bean>

 ...

<context:annotation-config/>
```

Would anyone please tell me where am i going wrong ????

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058037/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-tx

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are using an XML namespace (in this case context) without declaring it

Change your xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

You were also referencing http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd, which I don't think exists.

Comment: This worked for me. But can someone please explain me exactly what the error was and how these namespace resolve it. In previous declaration also we defined xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context".

Answer (score 5):

Take attention: when you use `context` namespace, you should update in XML head ***2*** attributes:

- `xmlns:context`
- **`xsi:schemaLocation`**.

Beginners used to add only `xmlns:context` and forget about 2 new entries to `xsi:schemaLocation`:

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd"
......
>
```

Answer (score 4):

If using Spring 4.0, here's what I found:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">
```

It worked for me. Found the reference here: http://javahash.com/spring-4-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-full-example/

Comment: how about context for version 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your xml file.

```
<xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

And

```
<xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

.

Answer (score 0):

finally got solution
just add this contain in XML file

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
</bean>
```