# Class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

   <context:annotation-config/>


<context:component-scan base-package="org.dao.impl"/>

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.jdbcurl}; create=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

Below is the error I am getting.

```
Sep 11, 2014 12:03:45 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1d33a6b: startup date [Thu Sep 11 12:03:45 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 11, 2014 12:03:45 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 7 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 30; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
```

I am also getting "The fully qualified name of the bean's class, except if it serves only as a parent definition for child bean definitions." when I hover my mouse over class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" What does it mean?

Could someone help me resolve the issue. I am trying to work on a simple spring hibernate and mysql. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802982/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-contextannotation-config)

Answer (score 3):

Also adding this dependency to pom.xml worked for me :)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your error is more related to the fact that you are using an XML namespace without declaring it.

As explainted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802982/no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-contextannotation-config). Try to add `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd` to the schemaLocation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Comment: Or use the version less variant. So spring uses the highest version od the xsd file that is found in classpath.

Comment: Thanks @XavierDelamotte. What if Im using spring framework 4.0?

Answer (score -1):

Add **`buildPath commons-dpcp2.jar`**, 
if it is not available with you please follow [this link](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi).

Download and add your Build Path of your Eclipse.