# org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException... why?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I develop server using spring mvc and hibernate.
So, I write my server program using Spring mvc and maven.
However when I start my server program at tomcat server, Error occurs.
That is things expected. so, I search using my error message.
However I can't find answer. help me....

This is my servlet-context.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
  infrastructure -->

 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven />

 <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
  up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
  in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
 <beans:bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>

 <context:component-scan base-package="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari" />

 <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <beans:property name="url"
   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jinggumdari" />
  <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="mysql1234" />
 </beans:bean>

 <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
 <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
   <beans:list>
    <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Member</beans:value>
   </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
  <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
   <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
   </beans:props>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="memberDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.MemberDAOImpl">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="memberService"
  class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.MemberManageServiceImpl">
  <beans:property name="memberDAO" ref="memberDAO"></beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
 
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
 
 <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
   ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
 </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

This is my pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.jbnu</groupId>
 <artifactId>jinggumdari</artifactId>
 <name>server</name>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <properties>
  <java-version>1.6</java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>4.1.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.8.5</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
  <hibernate.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
   <exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- AspectJ -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
   <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- Logging -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.15</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
     <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- @Inject -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Servlet -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  

  <!-- Test -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.7</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Hibernate -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- JDBC -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.30</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- javax.persistence -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- apache DBCP -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
     <additionalProjectnatures>
      <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
     </additionalProjectnatures>
     <additionalBuildcommands>
      <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
     </additionalBuildcommands>
     <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
     <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
     <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
     <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
     <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

This is error messages.

```html
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 69 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 69; columnNumber: 67; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: matching wildcard is strict but no declaration can be found for 'tx:annotation-driven' element.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 69; columnNumber: 67; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: matching wildcard is strict but no declaration can be found for 'tx:annotation-driven' element.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
 ... 29 more
```

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058037/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-tx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your xsi:schemaLocation attribute is missing the schema for the *tx* namespace.

add

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
```

It is also weird that the tx:annotation-driven is in the middle of the beans. It might have a specific place in the xml specified by the schema, can't remember. You'll get a different specific error if it is in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks, I'll find accurate tx:annotation-driven.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with th answer given by Peter, the beans declaration should be like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

But generally we should use default namespace for `beans` instead of `mvc`, in that case the declaration becomes like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```