# Spring boot application failed with schema reference error

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have written simple rest service with spring boot and using context file. Project builds successfully. But unfortunately it fails with schema reference error when running.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:99) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:433) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:347) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4166) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(XSDHandler.java:4157) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHandler.java:2490) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2187) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:573) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2453) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1772) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347) [na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) [spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) [spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at lk.dialog.ist.starpoint.merchant.MerchantDirectoryApplication.main(MerchantDirectoryApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:643) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:582) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2175) [na:1.7.0_79]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2016-02-26 14:52:10.838  WARN 6280 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from URL [file:/E:/WorkSpaces/tmp/MerchantDirectory/target/classes/recycle-process-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 52; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.
2016-02-26 14:52:10.838 ERROR 6280 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from URL [file:/E:/WorkSpaces/tmp/MerchantDirectory/target/classes/recycle-process-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 52; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at lk.dialog.ist.starpoint.merchant.MerchantDirectoryApplication.main(MerchantDirectoryApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:458) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3237) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1917) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:766) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.merchant"></context:component-scan>
<context:property-placeholder location="file:src/main/resources/recycle-process.properties" />
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

<!-- Data Source Connection -->
<bean id="SPMerchantDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="${sp.db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${sp.db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${sp.db.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"></property>
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"></property>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select sysdate from dual"></property>
    <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="500"></property>
    <property name="maxWait" value="500"></property>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"></property>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"></property>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"></property>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="5000"></property>
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"></property>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Creating a Session Factory -->
<bean id="SPLocalSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="SPMerchantDS" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.entities"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="SPTransactionManager" name="SPTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SPLocalSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Please help me to identify and fix this problem (I have gone through several same kind of questions and still no luck)

Comment: `XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from URL [file:/E:/WorkSpaces/tmp/MerchantDirectory/target/classes/recycle-process-context.xml]` and `The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'`. All you need, just read text of error.

Comment: I tried with spring-tx-2.5.xsd,spring-tx-3.1.xsd, spring-tx-3.2.xsd and spring-tx-4.2.xsd, but still same error. please tell me exactly what should I do?

Comment: Pls share your spring config xml file i.e. recycle-process-contex‌​t.xml

Comment: Please find attached context file lines.

Answer (score 0):

this is your error line:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from URL [file:/E:/WorkSpaces/tmp/MerchantDirectory/target/classes/recycle-process-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 52; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.
```

The way to solve this is:

[The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058037/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-tx)

Comment: Seems its no the error in my context file. please find respective lines. <context:annotation-config /> <context:component-scan base-package="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.merchant"></context:component-scan> <context:property-placeholder location="file:src/main/resources/recycle-process.properties" /> <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />