# XML Namespace exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have searched on stackoverflow for similar problems but I could not understand the reason of exception in my file. I have a DTO of customer which has following customer-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/ http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.utd.controller" />
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"></bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"></bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="customerDao" class="com.utd.dao.CustomerDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="customerManager" class="com.utd.service.CustomerManagerImpl"></bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am getting following exception in tomcat logs:

```
27-Nov-2018 00:48:13.919 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
27-Nov-2018 00:48:14.378 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 55 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/customer-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 55; columnNumber: 29; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
```

Can you help me to understand why I am getting this exception and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd to http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd by specifying version and it should work.

for tx and other schema also change like this.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058037/the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-found-for-element-tx) thread

Comment: I have updated the question to show the error I am getting after changing the schema as you have indicated. Can you help me to resolve the error?